# Can a component subscribe to two different stores flux

Tags: reactjs, flux

Hello i just started using flux but it's still confusing me.
so i have a component named CoursePage in this i'm rendering courses and authors and they are fetched from the server separately, then i created two stores CourseStore and AuthorStore. The problem is i want my component to subscribe to these stores.

so is there a way a component to subscribe to two or more stores

Comment: Store in Flux are nothing but the listeners. So if your action is being listened by multiple store then it will update the respective data.

Comment: i have a loadCourses action listened in CourseStore  and loadAuthors listened in AuthorStore